# How to add all of the NLP features to the dataframe

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, feature-extraction

I first made dataframe

```
def pre_processing_songs_nlp(df):
      print('Extracting NLP features...')
      df['NLP Features'] = df['Cleaned Lyrics'].progress_apply(lambda x: nlp_pipeline(x))
      df = df.dropna()
```

then I was trying to add all of the NLP features to the dataframe

```
new_df = pre_processing_songs_nlp(new_df)
```

but it is giving some error like-

```
    0%|          | 0/5796 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Extracting NLP features...
error: bad escape \p
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you registered your progress bar with `tdqm`, with a line like `tqdm.pandas(desc="my bar!")` ?

Comment: Check https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/178#issuecomment-535427081

Comment: Yes i'm using tqdm to get a progress bar on long-loading processes ........                      
" from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook
tqdm_notebook().pandas() "